# rubyで非同期に実行した外部プログラムのプロセスIDを取得し、強制終了させたい。

Tags: ruby, windows

たとえば、rubyで

```
system('start "" cmd')
```

とすると、非同期で実行できますが、プロセスIDが取得できないので、強制終了できません。

```
i = Process.spawn("cmd")
```

とするとプロセスIDは取得できますが、`Process.kill("TERM", i)` で終了できません。

目下のところは、spawn() でidを取得し、`taskkill /im #{pid} /f /t` で強制終了しています。

rubyで`cmd`のプロセスIDを取得でき、かつ、強制終了する方法はありますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windowsの場合 `taskkill` で停止するのが良いようです。
[How to kill processes on Windows using Ruby | Simplificator](https://blog.simplificator.com/2016/01/18/how-to-kill-processes-on-windows-using-ruby/)

Answer (score 0):

強制終了するのにプロセスIDは使用していませんが・・・

```
require "win32ole"

def kill_process(exe_file)
  wmi = WIN32OLE.connect('winmgmts://')
  res = wmi.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_Process where CommandLine like '%#{exe_file}%'")
  res.each do |item|
    p item.ProcessID
    item.terminate
  end
end

kill_process("xxxxxx.exe")
```